# Measuring frame rate in View-based apps

Tags: android

What's the best method of measuring the frame rate in a standard "View-based" Android app? I don't have any custom Views or use OpenGL or anything like that, just stock Android Views in a Layout. I'm particularly interested in measuring the frame rate when scrolling a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the `ListView` and override its `onDraw` method and time the call to `super.onDraw`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your ListView has an id="@+id/list_view". Then you can do something like this.

```
view = findViewById(R.id.list_view)
currentFps = 0
currentTime = 0
view.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener {
    if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - currentTime > 1000) {
        currentTime  = systemClock.uptimeMillis()
        fpsValue = currentFps // This is your fps value in  previous second
        currentFps = 0
    } else {
        currentFps++
    }
}
```